# set focus angular way using Fat Plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to use FaT ( Focus At This ) Plugin ,

[Plugin Link](http://www.robertnyman.com/fat/demo.htm)

this is to add focus to an element . i am using it with Angularjs Directive . my problem is i am setting this inside directive by following way .

```
 $scope.$broadcast('setfocus',{"values":''})
```

this is broadcast to dynamicaly pass element name then below line to set focus written insiode directive ,

```
 FaT.setFocus("star_heading", true, false);
```

Everything thing works fine but the problem is once element become focus on ESC or click on other button i am not able to activate focus for other element . how can i remove or unset focus ?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before selecting the tag. This has nothing to do with [File Allocation Table](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fat/info).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté oops my mistake ... Focus At this what i meant!!